# Can't get javascript to detect css3 animationend

Tags: javascript, css-animations

I'm having trouble getting the javascript for my animationEnd working correctly.

I have a div ("diaDiv") that fades in when the page loads. I'm trying to get it to, once it is completely faded in, change a hidden div below it ("responseDiv") to be visible.

```
function displayText(){
    var element = document.getElementById('diaDiv');
    element.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd, document.getElementById('responseDiv').style.visibility = "visible", false);
    element.addEventListener('AnimationEnd, document.getElementById('responseDiv').style.visibility = "visible", false);
    element.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd, document.getElementById('responseDiv').style.visibility = "visible", false);
}
```

I've also tried it with putting the styling of responseDiv in another function, and simply calling that function from the event listener.

This seems to be what people are having work, but I'm not having much luck. If I have the function run onLoad(), the div is visible from the start, so I'm assuming it's an issue with my event listeners. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're missing `'`s and I believe you need a `function()`. Try

```
function displayText(){
    var element = document.getElementById('diaDiv');
    element.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
        document.getElementById('responseDiv').style.visibility = "visible" 
    }, false);
    element.addEventListener('AnimationEnd', function() { 
        document.getElementById('responseDiv').style.visibility = "visible" 
    }, false);
    element.addEventListener('webkitAnimationEnd', function() { 
        document.getElementById('responseDiv').style.visibility = "visible" 
    }, false);
}
```

Comment: Ah, great. I actually had the quotes, I just missed them typing in here, couldn't get the copy/paste to work properly for code. The "function(){...}"was what I needed though. Thanks a bunch!